# Android with Kotlin, unable to find element by id

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

After updating android studio to version 4.2 I am unable to find elements in an activity by their id name. At first I thought it was only a problem with the recyclerView, but I cannot find simple textViews or buttons even when it matches the id perfectly. What is happening here, it has broken all my android projects with hundreds of unresolved reference errors.

Comment: Rebuild the project. If that doesn't work, invalidate and restart.

Answer (score 3):

You might be using Synthetics, this is deprecated. I suggest you to migrate to  View Binding:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

For a proper solution I suggest giving more context on your question